# Test class for a scheduled batch is not firing the batch

Tags: apex, unit-test, batch, code-coverage

I have tried the class in a sandbox and works fine (i.e. it updates all of the accounts based on the attached event records). The test class refuses to fire the batch class and I get 0% coverage.

```
global class csLastActivityBatch implements Schedulable {
    global void execute(SchedulableContext SC) {   

      List<Account> AccountToUpdate = new List<Account>();


      List<Account> acc = [Select Id,
                                  Last_CS_Activity__c
                                   from Account 
                                   where Type='Customer' or Type='Reseller Customer' ];
      List<User> usr = [Select Id,
                                  Department
                                   from User 
                                   where Department='Customer Success' ];

      Map<Id,Date> accountMap = new Map<Id,Date>();

      for(AggregateResult ar : [Select AccountId, max(StartDateTime) 
                           from Event
                           where AccountId IN: acc 
                           and OwnerId IN: usr
                           and StartDateTime <= Today     
                           group by AccountId]) 
        { 

        accountMap.put(String.valueOf(ar.get('AccountId')),Date.valueOf(ar.get('expr0')));
        } 

      for(Id parentId: accountMap.keySet())  
        {
        AccountToUpdate.add(new Account(Id = parentId, Last_CS_Activity__c = accountMap.get(parentId)));
        }

     Update AccountToUpdate;




    }
}
```

Here is the test class:

```
@isTest
private class testcsLastActivityBatch {
@isTest
    static void csActivityTestClass() 
    {    

        Profile pp = [SELECT Id FROM Profile WHERE Name='CS User'];

        User u = new User();
        u.email = 'username2099NQG@Ducoxyz.com';
        u.CompanyName = 'TEST';
        u.Lastname = 'Last';
        u.Department = 'Customer Success';
        u.Title = 'title';
        u.Alias = 'alias';
        u.TimeZoneSidKey = 'America/Los_Angeles';
        u.EmailEncodingKey = 'UTF-8';
        u.LanguageLocaleKey = 'en_US';
        u.LocaleSidKey = 'en_US';
        u.IsActive = true;
        u.username = 'username2099NQG@Ducoxyz.com';
        u.ProfileId = pp.Id;
        insert u; 

        Account a = new Account();
        a.Name = 'Test Account XYXY';
        a.BillingCountry = 'United Kingdom';
        a.BillingCity = 'London';
        a.Type = 'Customer';
        a.Segment__c = 'Bank';
        a.AnnualRevenue = 10;
        a.Last_CS_Activity__c = date.ValueOf(<rc-c2d-number data-rc-number="'1968-09-20">'1968-09-20</rc-c2d-number>');
        insert a;

        Event t = new Event();
        t.Subject = 'Test Subject';
        t.ActivityDate = date.ValueOf(<rc-c2d-number data-rc-number="'1968-09-22">'1968-09-22</rc-c2d-number>');
        t.WhatId = a.id;
        t.type = 'Client services Call';
        t.ActivityDateTime = datetime.newInstance(1968, 9, 22, 13, 30, 0);
        t.DurationInMinutes = 60; 
        t.OwnerId = u.Id;
        insert t;

        t = [SELECT id, ActivityDate, OwnerId, AccountId, WhatId, StartDateTime FROM Event WHERE id= :t.id];  
        Update t;

        a = [SELECT id, Name, Last_CS_Activity__c, Type FROM Account WHERE id= :a.id];  
        Update a;

        Test.startTest();

            csLastActivityBatch sh1 = new csLastActivityBatch();
            String sch = '0 0 2 * * ?';
            String jobId = system.schedule('Test Check', sch, sh1);
            CronTrigger ct = [Select id , CronExpression, TimesTriggered from CronTrigger where id = :jobId];   
            System.assertEquals(sch,ct.CronExpression);
            System.assertEquals(0,ct.TimesTriggered);

        Test.stopTest();

        System.assertEquals(1,ct.TimesTriggered);
        System.assertEquals(a.Last_CS_Activity__c,t.ActivityDate);
    }   
}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

When you query a record, it is "copied" to memory, and may not represent the state of affairs in the database. This is a pretty common thing to do by accident. The solution is to re-query the data to verify that the new values are correct.

```
    CronTrigger ct = [Select id , CronExpression, TimesTriggered from CronTrigger where id = :jobId];   
    System.assertEquals(sch,ct.CronExpression);
    System.assertEquals(0,ct.TimesTriggered);

    Test.stopTest();
    // Get latest values from the database
    ct = [Select id , CronExpression, TimesTriggered from CronTrigger where id = :jobId];   
    System.assertEquals(1,ct.TimesTriggered);
    System.assertEquals(a.Last_CS_Activity__c,t.ActivityDate);
```

Comment: That was a good thought. The system assert still failed though.